# maxValue gives me an error in Mysql 5.6 but not in Mysql 5.1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, etl

Im running an old ETL program wrote in Java. that program worked ok when I stored data results into Mysql 5.1 using JDBC connector. But when I tried to store data in Mysql 5.6 I'm receiving the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL Syntax: check the manual that corresponds 
to your mysql server version for the right syntax use near 
'maxValue = maxValue + 10 WHERE primaryKeyName = 'run_Id'' at line 1."
```

I checked mysql website and maxValue is a reserved word in version 5.6. and in version 5.1 (link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html ) so it seems not a direct problem based on maxValue name in different mysql version.

I cannot understand why I'm receiving this error, additionally based on the fact that its a compiled program I don't have many code files to modify.

UPDATE----------
based on @wchiquito input i checked and in 5.1 is key but not reserved. anyone knows a turn around to surpass reserved words with legacy software?.

Comment: In 5.1 `MAXVALUE` is keyword but not reserved. In 5.5 `MAXVALUE` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @wchiquito you are right, it has the (r) letter in 5.5..

Comment: One option is to use something like [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) that allows you to modify the statement before it reaches the server (MySQL).